# Uninstall ubuntu linux/ Install windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I want to uninstall my ubuntu linux from the computer because it's very hard to use and install windows 7. What can i do in this case?(I have an original windows 7 on CD/DVD)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Linux only and want to remove it to install windows:

- Insert the DVD of windows 7 and format the full hard disk to remove Ubuntu and install Windows 7

If you have both OS installed I recomend you to use `OS-Uninstaller`

- You just need to boot from a Live CD with UBUNTU, install `OS-Uninstaller` and then remove the OS you want to delete (in this case Ubuntu)